# The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:\nstderr: \"The system cannot find the path specified. - Laravel Snappy

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-snappy

I am trying to export data to pdf using [laravel-snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy). I have

**Installed wkhtmltopdf-window**s

```
composer require wemersonjanuario/wkhtmltopdf-windows 0.12.2.3
```

**Install laravel-snappy**

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-snappy
```

**Added service provider in config/app.php**

```
Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider::class,
```

**Added aliases**

```
'PDF' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf::class,
'SnappyImage' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyImage::class,
```

**Published Config file**

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider"
```

Updated **config/snappy.php**

```
'pdf' => [
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => base_path('vendor\wemersonjanuario\wkhtmltopdf-windows\bin\64bit\wkhtmltopdf'),
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => [],
        'env'     => [],
        ],
```

**Got Error:**

```
    "message": "The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:\nstderr: \"The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n\"\nstdout: \"\"\ncommand: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --lowquality \"C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP\\knp_snappy5dcd3b81559d67.45448784.html\" \"C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP\\knp_snappy5dcd3b8155c8a2.62799911.pdf\".",
```

In this error, I noticed it is looking the `.exe` file at `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`. However, I have not mentioned this path in `config/snappy.php`.

So, I tried by updating the path directly into the `vendor/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/config/snappy.php`

Surprisingly, this works. So, I could not figure out why this `laravel-snappy` is not reading the path from `config/snappy.php` and instead reading from the vendor file.

Is there something, I am missing?

Comment: I did the same , but It just load and then show timeout error..

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issues, instead it was related to another package. Basically, this type of issues occurs because of some cache issue.

SO, you can try the following commands.

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
php artisan vendor:publish
```

especially, `cache:clear` and `config:clear` should fix your issue.

Comment: not worked this

Answer (score 0):

Try after installing WKHTMLTOPDF from here:

https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: Why? How would this solve the issue? What are the exact steps to perform the installation?

Comment: @mozway depending on OS version that you are using, you can install it. When installed correctly, the programming/installer adds command "wkhtmltopdf" to the command line or shell. If "wkhtmltopdf --version" command runs correctly, that means it is installed correctly. So please follow the steps on their website to do the installation depending on your OS.